# React Native variable scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scope, react-props

I have two components, a parent (ManySpace) and a child (OtherComponent). OtherComponent renders two ManySpace components with two different arrays for the manyspace prop.

Confuse the first ManySpace and second ManySpace component array contents.
For example MANYSPACE1 answer1 = abc , MANYSPACE2 answer1 = cba , two ManySpace component answer1 output is same not expected values.

I don't use const and let because using variables outside the render scope and don't use class variable because I use prop assignment like this

```
MANYSPACE = this.props.manyspace;

onSubmitEditing1 = () => {
    if (secondinput) { this.secondref.focus(); }
    else if (thirdinput) { this.thirdref.focus(); }
    else { Keyboard.dismiss(); }
};
```

How I solve this problem thanks. hope I to explained the my problem
ManySpace Component ->

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; //and other imports
let MANYSPACE;
let icerik;
let firsttext;
let firstinput;
let answer1;
let answerlength1;
let secondtext;
let secondinput;
class ManySpace extends Component {
    render() {
        MANYSPACE = this.props.manyspace;
        icerik = MANYSPACE[0].icerik;
        firsttext = MANYSPACE[0].firsttext;
        firstinput = MANYSPACE[0].firstinput;
        if (firstinput) {
            answer1 = MANYSPACE[0].firstinput.answer1;
            answerlength1 = answer1.length;
        }

        secondtext = MANYSPACE[0].secondtext;
        secondinput = MANYSPACE[0].secondinput;
        if (secondinput) {
            answer2 = MANYSPACE[0].secondinput.answer2;
            answerlength2 = answer2.length;
        }
        return ()
    }
}
```

--My other component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; //and other imports
const MANYSPACE1 = [
    {
        icerik: 'lorem ipsum',
        firsttext: 'lorem ipsum',
        firstinput: {
            answer1: 'lorem ipsum'
        },
        secondtext: 'lorem ipsum'
    }
];

const MANYSPACE2 = [
    {
        icerik:'lorem ipsum',
        firsttext: 'lorem ipsum',
        firstinput: {
            answer1: 'lorem ipsum'
        },
        secondtext: 'lorem ipsum',
        secondinput: {
            answer2: 'lorem ipsum'
        },
        thirdinput: {
            answer3: 'lorem ipsum'
        }
    }
];  
class OtherComponent extends Component {
    <ManySpace
        manyspace={MANYSPACE1}
    />
    <ManySpace
        manyspace={MANYSPACE2}
    />
}
```

Comment: Why are you saving these values in global variables?

Comment: If you have more than one `ManySpace` instances, you should not keep the variables outside of the component, because then your different instances will overwrite them.

Comment: "*I use variables outside the render scope and don't use class variable*" - well, there's your problem. Don't do that.

Comment: How can I reach to variables ManySpace class as if it were in onSubmitEditing1 function

Comment: I can't even figure out what you're *trying* to do by completely subverting React's normal data mechanisms.

Comment: @Bergi sorry problem is my English spelling ?

Comment: I think you may have some fundamental misconceptions about how React is supposed to be used. Data goes one way: down. If you need to modify data at a higher level you pass a function to the component that needs to modify it. (Or you switch to a different state management system, like Redux/etc.)

Comment: Seems like you need a bit more understanding of the scope of `this`. It's a bit hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish but setting properties to `this` would allow you to access class variables.

Comment: @DaveNewton because I just want to reach variable all component (is ManySpace class base component), any scope area

Comment: @Radex26 Then you probably want something like Redux/etc. instead of treachery like this. Or you need to pass the data to all the components you're talking about. It's not at all clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know use redux but is not resolved with redux, thanks for helping

Comment: @Radex26 Then you're probably not using Redux right either.